# How can I set Desktop location for fileImporter in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying set Desktop location for user to conform the permission to access to Desktop, as we know in SwiftUI fileImporter, it just lunch as a window and let user to chose the wished item or items what ever they want, but I want limit this option just for a specific folder like Desktop, as you can see in Button, I just need to access to Desktop with user permission, is there a way for such a task?

Currently with this below code user can select any folder wants, which I want limit it to just Desktop.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var fileImporterIsPresented: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Button("Give access to Desktop") {
                
                fileImporterIsPresented = true
                
            }
            .fileImporter(isPresented: $fileImporterIsPresented, allowedContentTypes: [.folder], allowsMultipleSelection: false, onCompletion: { result in
                
                switch result {
                case .success(let urls):
                    
                    if let unwrappedURL: URL = urls.first {
                        
                        print(unwrappedURL)
                        
                    }
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error selecting file \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                
            })
            
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this macOS native app or multi-platform one?

Comment: It is native macOS, but if you have any answer maybe I can find NS version of it as well or try to build a NS version of it.

Comment: Well, we cannot disallow completely to change directory in open dialog (used for file import), but in native `NSOpenDialog` you can track directory changes with delegate and actually manage availability to select anything outside of desired location.

Comment: What I tried so far was playing with panel.directoryURL to set a default but again, the issue is steal there after lunching panel in Desktop level, user can select any folder, which I am not happy with it. I did not tried your comment and not sure how it would works.